# Can headless-chrome cast webgl dashboard to a google cast TV?

Tags: google-chrome, google-cast, google-chrome-headless

I have a web-GL based analytics dashboard. The Google Cast device does not render WebGL content internally.

Can chrome-headless running on a local server be used render and cast a dashboard to a google-cast device?

I do not want to have a desktop system for this job, hence my interest in chrome-headless and google cast.

Comment: seems like if you've got a headless-chrome and a google cast TV ... you could just plug one into the other and thereby give it a head ...

Answer (score 0):

Google Cast Receiver apps do support WebGL. However, since it is running on hardware with limited resources, the performance will not be the same as on a desktop.

It is possible to cast a Chrome tab to a Cast receiver. However, this only works with the desktop version of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

For sure you can run google chrome inside Xvfb + VNC (to start and control chrome browser) and cast its tab to google cast device.
Problem with it can be some security issues with access to the server where chrome browser is started. More secure can be to use a separate device to cast like rPi or run it inside docker image.